# OCSP recording with JMeter

Tags: certificates, ocsp

How can I record an application which is using OCSP security with the help of JMeter?

I am not able to record the application i.e. a native app with the help of JMeter as it is using OCSP protocol for security.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [JSR223 samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or [Beanshell samplers](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/testing-complex-logic-with-jmeter-beanshell/) to encode and decode reqest and responce, with help of open source third-party Java library from [Bouncy castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/).

Follow this steps to record application requests which is using OCSP:

- [Load Test OCSP With JMeter](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-load-test-ocsp-with-jmeter)

Check this guides for more information :

- [Recording with JMeter Proxy](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/)

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer that almost entirely does contain software recommendation links? I also think you misunderstood the question. I think the question does ask how to spoof an OSCP response rather than load testing an OSCP server.

Comment: Probably you are right but author does not tell about spoofing directly. 
He asks about how to record requests from apllications with OCSP using JMeter. 
So, the guide describe steps to do so. I think there is no need to copypaste steps from that guide to here, or it is ok?

Comment: Answers are meant to be self-contained and not only a collection of links - links can be outdated and/or go dead.

Comment: hm, yes, it make sence for now, thanks for your explanation!